# Footnote referencing footnote in different stream using reledmac

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

I need the **ability to have a foonote in one stream be able to reference a footnote in another stream**. There are two series of footnotes defined. I want to be able to cross-reference between the two series of notes. So, I could have a footnote in series A reference a footnote in series B.

The answer must take into account that my MWE is "de-duplicating" footnotes in the second footnotes stream (a problem that was solved [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/416005/multiple-references-to-the-same-footnote-per-page-with-multiple-sets-of-footnote)). So, this is a bit different than other posts that attempt the same thing without this added complexity.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package


%footnote sets arrangement
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{twocol}
\colalignX{\justifying}
\makeatletter
\bhooknoteX[A]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\bhookgroupX[A]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\makeatother
\let\footnote\footnoteA

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\roman{footnote}}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

%This makes the footnote numbering restart for every page
\MakePerPage{footnoteB} %the perpage package command
\let\footnoteBlist\relax%Declare a list
\newcommand{\onlyonefootnoteB}[1]{%The command to be call instead of \footnoteB
    \xifinlist{\detokenize{#1}}{\footnoteBlist}%
    {}%True : does nothing
    {%False : add to the list + add footnote
        \listxadd{\footnoteBlist}{\detokenize{#1}}%
        \footnoteB{#1}%
    }%
}

\bhookgroupX[B]{%
    \global\let\footnoteBlist\relax%Declare a list
}


\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor\footnote{test text A} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna\onlyonefootnoteB{test 1} aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud\footnote{test text B} exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor\footnote{test text A} in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur\onlyonefootnoteB{test 2} sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,\onlyonefootnoteB{test 1} sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your need. It is not the first time I don't understand it. What do you mean by "ability to have a foonote in one stream be able to reference a footnote in another stream" ? Do you mean using cross referencing between notes. Or do you mean an other  thing?

Comment: There are two series of footnotes defined. I want to be able to cross-reference between the two series of notes. So, I could have a footnote in series A reference a footnote in series B.

Comment: Please and this sentence in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with classical `\ref` and `\label`.

The problem, in your case, is that you made

```
\let\footnote\footnoteA
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\roman{footnote}}
```

So.
 1. You tell that `\footnote` command is the same as `\footnoteA` command
 2. But you use the value of the `footnote`  counter to print the footnote number for series A, and not the value of `footnoteA` counter, which should be used.  Indeed, you could see that footnote A, with your code, have no number typeset.

So just change `\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\roman{footnote}}` to `\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\roman{footnoteA}}`.

Here a MWE of crossref.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package


%footnote sets arrangement
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{twocol}
\colalignX{\justifying}
\makeatletter
\bhooknoteX[A]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\bhookgroupX[A]{\setstretch {\setspace@singlespace}}
\makeatother
\let\footnote\footnoteA

\renewcommand{\thefootnoteA}{\roman{footnoteA}}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000

%This makes the footnote numbering restart for every page
\MakePerPage{footnoteB} %the perpage package command
\let\footnoteBlist\relax%Declare a list
\newcommand{\onlyonefootnoteB}[1]{%The command to be call instead of \footnoteB
    \xifinlist{\detokenize{#1}}{\footnoteBlist}%
    {}%True : does nothing
    {%False : add to the list + add footnote
        \listxadd{\footnoteBlist}{\detokenize{#1}}%
        \footnoteB{#1}%
    }%
}

\bhookgroupX[B]{%
    \global\let\footnoteBlist\relax%Declare a list
}


\begin{document}
\ref{footnoteA:crossref}

Lorem ipsum dolor\footnote{test text A} sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna\onlyonefootnoteB{test 1} aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud\footnote{\label{footnoteA:crossref}test text B} exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor\footnote{test text A} in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur\onlyonefootnoteB{test 2} sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,\onlyonefootnoteB{test 1 (see \ref{footnoteA:crossref})} sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\end{document}
```